# Switching character locations in MIPS Assembly

Tags: string, assembly, mips

I'm trying to print out

```
Hello, world.
ello, world.H
llo, world.He
lo, world.Hel
o, world.Hell
, world.Hello
 world.Hello,
world.Hello,
orld.Hello, w
rld.Hello, wo
ld.Hello, wor
d.Hello, worl
.Hello, world
Hello, world.
```

using only this string in memory `String:    .asciiz   "Hello, world."`. So far this is my code:

```
    .text
String:    .asciiz "Hello, world."
x:         .float 13

    .data 
Main:       lw $t0,x
            jal PrintString
            li $v0, 10
            syscall

PrintString:    la $a0,String
                li $v0,4
                syscall
                bgtz $t0, MoveString
                jr $ra

MoveString: (CODE)
```

but I'm not sure what to put in the MoveString label. I need to shift the characters in `String` by one, and subtract what is in `x` by 1. I'm not sure how to go about doing this. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple notes first:

- You have `.text` and `.data` mixed up
- Go ahead and add a newline to the end of the string, it'll make displaying a bit nicer:

  ```
  String:    .asciiz "Hello, world.\n"
  ```
- Assuming that 13 is used for the length of the string, you should use an integer instead of a float:

  ```
  x:         .word 13
  ```

Now, onto the problem. There's two ways to do this: 1) rotate the string in-place and call `syscall 4` each time, or 2) keep the string as it is and print it one letter at a time, playing with the index instead to achieve the rotation effect. You've chosen method 1, so let's go with that.

Start by writing some pseudocode. You need a subroutine that'll rotate the string stored at `$a0` to the left by one letter. Immediately, you should be thinking about some kind of loop that iterates over each letter in the string:

```
for int index from 0 to 12
    copy letter from (index + 1) to index
```

But wait: what happens to the first letter? It'll get clobbered. And what happens when we reach the end? We'll copy something outside the bounds of `String` to the last letter slot. So let's work around it by storing the first letter to a temporary register:

```
temp = letter[0]

for int index from 0 to 11
    copy letter from (index + 1) to index

letter[12] = temp
```

That's better; that should do it. Next question: how do we do this in MIPS?

We know that `$a0` will hold the address of the string, so let's take that for granted. We need at least one temporary register -- since we're already using `$t0` for `x`, let's use `$t1` to hold the first letter:

```
MoveString:
lb $t1, String
```

We also need an index register, so let's use `$t2` for that. Initialize it to zero:

```
li $t2, 0
```

It'd be nice to just increment our address register once for each letter, but we don't want to clobber `$a0` because it'll mess up `PrintString`. So let's copy it to `$a1` for our loop:

```
move $a1, $a0
```

Lastly, we need to know how long the string is, so let's load another copy of `x` into `$t3`:

```
lb $t3, x
sub $t3, $t3, 1               ; We're only iterating over the first 12 letters,
                              ; since the last letter is done manually with temp
```

Now we can start the loop. We need to copy the letter (which is just a byte) from `$a1 + 1` to `$a1`:

```
MoveStringLoop:
lb $t4, 1($a1)                  ; Load the letter from (address + 1)
sb $t4, 0($a1)                  ; Store it to (address)
add $a1, $a1, 1                 ; Increment our address
add $t2, $t2, 1                 ; Increment our index
blt $t2, $t3, MoveStringLoop    ; Loop again if index < (length - 1)

sb $t1, 0($a1)                  ; Copy the temp letter to the end of the string
```

That should be it. After that, we can decrement `x` and go back to `PrintString`:

```
sub $t0, $t0, 1
b PrintString
```

This isn't an optimal solution by any means; I'm sure a real compiler and some better coding could get the job done in half the instructions. But since you're learning how to write assembly, don't worry about micro-optimization for now. Here's the final code along with its output:

```
    .data
String:    .asciiz "Hello, world.\n"
x:         .word 13

    .text 
Main:       lw $t0,x
            jal PrintString
            li $v0, 10
            syscall

PrintString:    la $a0,String
                li $v0,4
                syscall
                bgtz $t0, MoveString
                jr $ra

MoveString:
                lb $t1, String
                li $t2, 0
                move $a1, $a0
                lb $t3, x
                sub $t3, $t3, 1

MoveStringLoop:
                    lb $t4, 1($a1)
                    sb $t4, 0($a1)
                    add $a1, $a1, 1
                    add $t2, $t2, 1
                    blt $t2, $t3, MoveStringLoop

                sb $t1, 0($a1)

                sub $t0, $t0, 1
                b PrintString
```

Output:

```
Hello, world.
ello, world.H
llo, world.He
lo, world.Hel
o, world.Hell
, world.Hello
 world.Hello,
world.Hello,
orld.Hello, w
rld.Hello, wo
ld.Hello, wor
d.Hello, worl
.Hello, world
Hello, world.
```